# como fijar el ancho de un selectonemenu en primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Tengo varios combos, y quiero que todos se vean del mismo tamaño, pero como la lista que los llena, en algunos casos es larga, el combo se hace mas largo y se ve disparejo, como puedo fijar un tamaño para todos

```
<p:fieldset legend="Bien Armonizado" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500">
  <p:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-3" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">

    <p:outputLabel value="#{sccbienarmonizadomsgs['sccbienarmonizado.cveidcapitulo.title']}:*" />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="cveIdCapitulo" value="#{SccBienArmonizadoComponent.sccbienarmonizado.sccPartidaGeneral.cveIdCapitulo}" filter="true" requiredMessage="#{sccbienarmonizadomsgs['sccbienarmonizado.title']}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{SccCapituloComponent.listSccCapitulos()}" var="current" itemValue="#{current.cveIdCapitulo}" itemLabel="#{current.desCapitulo}"></f:selectItems>
      <f:ajax execute="cveIdConcepto" event="change" render="cveIdConcepto"></f:ajax>
    </p:selectOneMenu>


    <p:outputLabel value="#{sccbienarmonizadomsgs['sccbienarmonizado.cveidconcepto.title']}:*" />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="cveIdConcepto" value="#{SccBienArmonizadoComponent.sccbienarmonizado.sccPartidaGeneral.cveIdConcepto}" filter="true" requiredMessage="#{sccbienarmonizadomsgs['sccbienarmonizado.title']}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{SccCapituloComponent.listSccCapituloSccConceptos(SccBienArmonizadoComponent.sccbienarmonizado.sccPartidaGeneral.cveIdCapitulo)}" var="current" itemValue="#{current.cveIdConcepto}" itemLabel="#{current.desConcepto}"></f:selectItems>
      <f:ajax execute="cveIdPartidaGeneral" event="change" render="cveIdPartidaGeneral"></f:ajax>
    </p:selectOneMenu>


    <p:outputLabel value="#{sccbienarmonizadomsgs['sccbienarmonizado.cveidpartidageneral.title']}:*" />
    <p:selectOneMenu id="cveIdPartidaGeneral" value="#{SccBienArmonizadoComponent.sccbienarmonizado.sccPartidaGeneral.cveIdPartidaGeneral}" filter="true" requiredMessage="#{sccbienarmonizadomsgs['sccbienarmonizado.title']}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{SccConceptoComponent.listSccConceptoSccPartidaGenerals(SccBienArmonizadoComponent.sccbienarmonizado.sccPartidaGeneral.cveIdConcepto, SccBienArmonizadoComponent.sccbienarmonizado.sccPartidaGeneral.cveIdCapitulo)}" var="current"
        itemValue="#{current.cveIdPartidaGeneral}" itemLabel="#{current.desPartidaGeneral}"></f:selectItems>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Crea un estilo con el ancho deseado:

```
.ancho200 { width: 200px !important}
```

Aplica el estilo a tus combos:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="cveIdCapitulo" value="#{SccBienArmonizadoComponent.sccbienarmonizado.sccPartidaGeneral.cveIdCapitulo}" filter="true" requiredMessage="#{sccbienarmonizadomsgs['sccbienarmonizado.title']}" styleClass="ancho200">
...
<p:selectOneMenu id="cveIdConcepto" value="#{SccBienArmonizadoComponent.sccbienarmonizado.sccPartidaGeneral.cveIdConcepto}" filter="true" requiredMessage="#{sccbienarmonizadomsgs['sccbienarmonizado.title']}" styleClass="ancho200">
...
<p:selectOneMenu id="cveIdPartidaGeneral" value="#{SccBienArmonizadoComponent.sccbienarmonizado.sccPartidaGeneral.cveIdPartidaGeneral}" filter="true" requiredMessage="#{sccbienarmonizadomsgs['sccbienarmonizado.title']}" styleClass="ancho200">
```

No es lo más elegante.